# Why getLocationOnScreen(location) always returns 0?

Tags: android, view, nestedscrollview

In my `FragmentLayout` I have a `LinearLayout` with multiple subviews (`TextView`, `CardView`). I want to find the top offset of all `LinearLayout` views but I always get zero.
This is my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

    nestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lll);

    int childCount = linearLayout.getChildCount();
    int[] location = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View v = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        v.getLocationOnScreen(location);

        Log.e("locX", location[0] + "");
        Log.e("locY", location[1] + "");

    }


    return view;
}
```

And this is my layout xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>              
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lll">

            // views are there 

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write the function to find location in `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` method or post the task on handler with 100 millisecond delay.

Comment: i am outsize an activity or fragment. how do i do that

Comment: Try, the code within in new Handler ().post(...... v.getLocationOnScreen(location); .....);

Comment: how to utlize this in onBindView?

Answer (score 0):

Your screen is not ready when you call onCreate(). To get all the data of the screen you need to wait until it is fully finished. You can use:

```
your_main_layout_here.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        // Remove the Global observer once it is called
        your_main_layout_here.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        // Your code here, i.e. check the view's location
        }
    });
```

And then