# getLocationOnScreen always returns 0 on widget position

Tags: android

I am trying to find the position of widgets but somehow it always returns `0`. I have followed most suggestions but all of them still returns `0`. I finally ended up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224844/how-to-get-the-absolute-coordinates-of-a-view), but still it returns a `0`. I have read somewhere that the reason it returns a `0` is because I am calling for the position before `onCreate()` has finished parsing the layout specified in the accompanying `.xml` file.

Where then should I put the call to the positions then?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fuelCalculationConstraintLayout"
    tools:context=".FuelCalculation">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewIconHome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_home" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewSettingValues"
            android:text="Settings:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageViewIconHome"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:height="30dp"
            android:width="100dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewScratchPad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Scratch Pad"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
package com.example.fuelcalculation3

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Point
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class FuelCalculation : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fuel_calculation)

        val updateTextViewSettingValues = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewSettingValues)
        val updateTextViewScratchPad = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewScratchPad)
        val imageIconHomeClick = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageViewIconHome)

        imageIconHomeClick.setOnClickListener(){
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        fun View.getLocationOnScreen(): Point {
            val location = IntArray(2)
            this.getLocationOnScreen(location)
            return Point(location[0], location[1])
        }

        val location = updateTextViewSettingValues.getLocationOnScreen()
        val absX = location.x
        val absY = location.y

        val getTextViewSettingsRootView = updateTextViewSettingValues.rootView
        val getTextViewSettingsValueWidth = updateTextViewSettingValues.width
        val getTextViewSettingsValueTop = updateTextViewSettingValues.top
        val getTextViewSettingsValueLeft = updateTextViewSettingValues.left
        val getTextViewSettingsValueRight = updateTextViewSettingValues.right
        val getTextViewSettingsValueMeasuredWidth = updateTextViewSettingValues.measuredWidth
        val getTextViewSettingsValueA = updateTextViewSettingValues.measuredWidth


        updateTextViewScratchPad.text = "Top=$getTextViewSettingsValueTop" // returns 0
        updateTextViewScratchPad.text = "$absX" // returns 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Why getLocationOnScreen(location) always returns 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790355/why-getlocationonscreenlocation-always-returns-0). You are to use `postDelayed` or `getViewTreeObserver` to get view position after an activity has rendered. Maybe you should use `requestLayout`.